# pandas - datetime - dropping seconds and milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a datetime column. I want to retain only until minutes and drop the seconds and milliseconds.

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['SubmitTimePst'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SubmitTimePst']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```